# Macro in Outlook for Automatic email

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to create an automatic mail response to the email which is currently active when I press a macro button.

Automatic email body should be read from an outside file - the format is `.txt`.

Aim: when I press a macro button it reads the contents of that `.txt` file and gives an auto reply to the active email.

Is this possible with a macro or VBA?

Comment: Seconded. 0 accepts from 7 question means you aren't participating properly in the community.

Answer (score 2):

This procedure (along with the three ancillary functions below it) will take the currently open or selected email, and reply to it using the text inside whatever text file you specify in the filepath at the top.

```
Sub ReplyCurrentMsg()

  ' ************************
  ' change this to point to the file you
  ' want to put in the message body
  ' when running the macro
  ' ************************
  Const TEXT_FILE_PATH As String = "C:\My Files\file_to_include.txt"

  Dim obj As Object
  Dim msg As Outlook.mailItem
  Dim msgReply As Outlook.mailItem
  Dim fileNum As Integer
  Dim fileContents As String

  Set obj = GetCurrentItem
  If TypeName(obj) = "MailItem" Then
    Set msg = obj
    Set msgReply = msg.Reply

    fileNum = FreeFile
    ' http://www.exceluser.com/explore/questions/vba_textcols.htm
    Open TEXT_FILE_PATH For Input As #fileNum
      fileContents = Input$(LOF(fileNum), 1)
    Close #fileNum

    With msgReply
      .Body = fileContents
      .Display ' or .Send
    End With

  End If
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
  Select Case True
  Case IsExplorer(Application.ActiveWindow)
    Set GetCurrentItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
  Case IsInspector(Application.ActiveWindow)
    Set GetCurrentItem = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
  End Select
End Function
Function IsExplorer(itm As Object) As Boolean
  IsExplorer = (TypeName(itm) = "Explorer")
End Function
Function IsInspector(itm As Object) As Boolean
  IsInspector = (TypeName(itm) = "Inspector")
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Just so I understand you what it to iterate through all active/enable email then send out content in a text file or the text file as an attachment.

Here is a link to show how to read text files.

Hey, take look at the link [VBA read text files](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/06/vba-read-text-files-with-leading.html)

see if this helps.

Comment: No My aim is that Read the contained  of Mail from a text file and send the mail to client, when i press that macro key

Comment: Ok. You want to create a macro button that reads information of a text file then send to as reply to the mail client or mail message presently viewing.   try this one http://www.answermysearches.com/how-to-send-an-outlook-email-with-vba-macros/340/

Comment: http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Outlook-Send-E-mail-Without-Security-Warning Also this.